# How to add columns in one slide in divi slider?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add two columns on one slide on the full width slider on the Divi theme in wordpress but I don't found how to add it,
I need an image on the left and text on the right as shown on the below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's actually built-in functionality. You just need to add the image and and it will automatically place it like your screenshot. If you want it on the right there is a dropdown for that as well.

Comment: I am looking for same thing but I did not find it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to build a slider or carousel is to use the [Free Divi carousel](https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousels-slider-for-divi/) plugin

and those have almost 17+ sliders they said. So [divi carousel slider](https://divicarousels.com/) will be easy for those.